# Minimum value of length of tangent of the ellipse $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$, intercepted between the co-ordinate axes

Tags: conic-sections

I have taken a parameter $(a \cos c, b \sin c)$ where $c$ is the eccentric angle and the tangent passing through this point cuts the x-axis at the point $(a \cos c, 0)$ and y-axis at $(0,b \sin c)$.

After this I have calculated the the length using Pythagoras theorem. But I couldn't get the minimum value.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by minimum length? Are you talking about the ellipse [minor axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length of tangent intercepted:
$\sqrt { \frac {a^2}{ {cos}^2 t}+ \frac {b^2 }{{sin}^2t}}$
= $\sqrt { a^2 {sec}^2 t+ b^2 {cosec}^2t}$
= $\sqrt { a^2{tan}^2t+a^2+ b^2 {cot}^2t+b^2}$
Using AM-GM inequality:
$\frac {a^2{tan}^2t+b^2 {cot}^2t} 2 \ge \sqrt {a^2{tan}^2t.b^2 {cot}^2t}$
So ${a^2{tan}^2t+b^2 {cot}^2t}  \ge 2ab $
Therefore required minimum value is $a+b$